# Grafana dashboard display database name error with TDengine

Tags: tdengine

I'm using grafana dashboard [15167](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/15167) with TDengine database v2.3.3.0 .

The databases are db02, db3, log, test .
But in Grafana dashboard, it's db02, db32, log, test.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update grafana 15167 to the latest version (revision 27), it fixed the problem.